# PSET 5 - Speller.c returns exit code of 2 and not 0

Tags: c, cs50

Whenever I run check50/submit50 on speller it says this:

expected exit code 0, not 2

I also saw this happening with other people. Some people said that the cause of this was altering programs such as dictionary.h and speller.c, but this kept happening even after I reset all changes to the programs. Anyone have any suggestions?

Error message:

```
:) dictionary.c exists 
:( speller compiles
expected exit code 0, not 2
:| handles most basic words properly
can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

Here's my dictionary.c code:
https://pastebin.com/N1aMNqmX

speller.c code:
https://pastebin.com/AFV9eHVm

Comment: The problem is with the return value of the `main()` function. That's not in the file you linked to.

Comment: Post a [mre] here, not as a link to another site.

Comment: I can't find the line of code where main() returns 2. It's only returns 0 or 1.

Comment: I agree, I don't see it, either.

Comment: The program compiles and works as expected when I use "make" locally.

Comment: You must have changed something, maybe you uploaded the wrong file.

Comment: There's no way for us to tell what you're doing wrong with `check50`. We can just look at the code you posted, and it looks OK.

Comment: Looks like it does not even compile with the checker. Given it comes after the line `:( speller compiles` I presume the exit code is from the compiler and not your program

Comment: The program does not compile as C because `node *table[N];` cannot be defined as a global variable with `N` defined as `const unsigned int N = 676;` Define `N` as `#define N 676`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program does not compile as C because `node *table[N];` cannot be defined as a global variable with `N` defined as `const unsigned int N = 676;` Define `N` as `#define N 676`

The exit code of `2` might be produced because of a compilation error.

Without this problem, the code compiles and runs fine.